# Debug and Trace Write/WriteLine not outputting to output in Visual Studio 2010 C# Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I can not get Debug or Trace to work in Visual Studio 2010 C# Express. I have "Redirect all output to immediate window" - Unchecked. Nothing is going to output window.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Trace.Write("Hello World");
Trace.WriteLine("Hello World");
Debug.Write("Hello World2");
Debug.WriteLine("Hello World2");
```

Comment: What type of project is it (console, web, etc.)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure that both checkboxes "Define DEBUG constant" and "Define TRACE constant" in project properties on page Build are checked.

Comment: Thank-You. This was my issue.

Answer (score 7):

Right click in the output window and make sure 'Program Output' is checked.